# Extract output values from disk image file as strings in Linux

Tags: linux, string, bash, text-extraction

I have an .img file from which I would like to extract 2 values derived with fdisk, as strings in 2 variables.

```
fdisk -l /home/documents/image-of-sd-card.img
Disk /home/documents/image-of-sd-card.img: 14,84 GiB, 15931539456 bytes, 31116288 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc680d152

Device                                    Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/home/documents/image-of-sd-card.img1        8192   655359   647168  316M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/home/documents/image-of-sd-card.img2      655360 31115263 30459904 14,5G 83 Linux
```

The values I would need are the last unit from "Sector size" (512) and the End size of the second partition (31115263).
How to achieve that? I would prefer a Bash based solution so that I could integrate this into an existing Shell script.

As an absolute beginner in Linux I just played around with some greb commands but to no avail.

Comment: What was your attempt? Do you now grep, awk, etc ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a steps by step explanation to help you in your bash learning

```
raw_content=$(fdisk -l /home/documents/image-of-sd-card.img)

sector_size=
second_partition_size=
while read i 
do 

    if [[ "$i" == "Sector size"* ]]; then
        echo ">>>>$i" 
        echo "$i" | cut -d ' ' -f 7
        sector_size=$(echo "$i" | cut -d ' ' -f 7)
    elif [[ "$i" == "/home/documents/image-of-sd-card.img2"* ]]; then
        echo ">>>>$i" 
        echo "$i" | awk -F' ' '{ print $3 }'
        second_partition_size=$(echo "$i" | awk -F' ' '{ print $3 }')        
    fi

done <<< "$raw_content"

echo -e "\nResults:"

echo "sector_size: $sector_size"
echo "second_partition_size: $second_partition_size"
```

**Output:**

[image]

### Explanation

- `raw_content=$(...)` will save all the output in a var
- `while read i ... done <<< "$raw_content"` will iterate line by line and set the value in **i** var
- `if [[ "$i" == "Sector size"* ]];` will ask if string starts with ...
- `echo "$i" | cut -d ' ' -f 7` will split by one space and get you the desired column
- `echo "$i" | awk -F' ' '{ print $3 }'` will split by several spaces and get you the desired column

### Recommended lectures

- [In Bash, how can I check if a string begins with some value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172352/in-bash-how-can-i-check-if-a-string-begins-with-some-value)
- [Use space as a delimiter with cut command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816820/use-space-as-a-delimiter-with-cut-command)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/66612752/3957754

Comment: Awesome. That does exactly what I need. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

With `fdisk` installed, you usually also have `sfdisk` available, which is a "script-oriented" fdisk. You can give it the `--json` (or `-J`) option to output the information in a more structured format (try out just entering `sfdisk -J /path/to/device` to see the entire output), which can then be processed by a JSON processor ([jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) for example) that can precisely extract what you need. Use `"$(...)"` to capture the output, and assign it to a variable.

```bash
sectorsize="$(sfdisk -J /path/to/device | jq '.partitiontable.sectorsize')"
part2size="$(sfdisk -J /path/to/device | jq '.partitiontable.partitions[1].size')"
```

With more variables, you might want to combine the calls. Here's one example:

```bash
{ read sectorsize; read part2size; } < <(
  sfdisk -J /path/to/device | jq '.partitiontable | .sectorsize, .partitions[1].size'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be used for extracting the Sector size

```
 size=$(fdisk -l /home/documents/image-of-sd-card.img |awk
'/^Sector/ {print $4}')
```

Similar pattern matching can be used to extract the second required value.

```
second_end=$(fdisk -l /home/documents/image-of-sd-card.img |awk
 '/^img2/ {print $3}')
```

Comment: Those do not give any output in my case

Answer (score 0):

It might be better if you find some script-oriented tool like `sfdisk`,
and it will be safer.

Otherwise, this can be solved combination of grep/sed/owk or even by pure bash.

```
fdisk .... > tmpx;
A="$(
    sed -n '\|Sector size (logical/physical)|{ s|.*/ *||; s| *bytes *||; p };'  tmpx
    )"
B="$(  awk '/sd-card.img2/{print $3}'  tmpx  )"

echo "The-results---$A---$B---"

The-results---512---31115263---
```

Explanations for `sed` command:  `-n` says do-not-print to `sed`, while `p` is the print command. `sed` program starts by so called address `\| <regular expression> |` which works as a selector. Following block `{ ... }` is executed for the mathing lines and contains `s| <what> | <bywhat>|` where we request to replace any `<what> = .*/ *` (meaning anychar(.) repeated-arbitrarily(`*`) followed-by-slash(/) followed-by  space( ) repeated-arbitrarily(`*`)).
We replace `<what>` by the empty string. Then we replace (`s|...|..|`)
`<what>` = "bytes" together with any spaces. Finally we print (`p`) the result.

Explanation for `awk` command: For the lines matching the address `/..../`
command `print` executed to print third `$3` word on the line.

--

Pure `bash` solution:

```
A="error"; B="error"; 
while read a b c d e f g h  ; do 
    [ "$a,$b,$c,,$e,$f" == "Sector,size,(logical/physical):,,bytes,/" ] && A="$g";
    [[ "$a" == *sd-card.img2 ]] && B="$c"; 
done < tmpx;
echo "The-results---$A---$B---"
```

Note: `[ ... == ... ]` is different from `[[ ... == ... ]]`.